# how to get_option from backend to front-end

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a plugin and I want to add in the backend a Checkbox that when clicked hides and element in the Front End.

My problem is how to use get_option properly because I really cannot figure it out and I am stuck in this position for 2 days and I have tried everything I know but I am a total begginer in PHP and plugin development, my main languages are HTML/css/js and I am really bad with dynamic content as a whole.

So, my code look like this:

```
function vsuc_page_html() { ?>
<div class="wrap vsuc-wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_errors() ?>
        <?php settings_fields('vsuc_option_group'); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vsuc_checkbox1" name="vsuc_checkbox1" value="style1" 
        onclick="check_css()" checked >
```

The checkbox works, I see changes in the console, but I see an error that the class that I am calling from front-end is not defined: (header_title is not defined)

```
const header_title = document.getElementById("header_title");
function check_css() {
    header_title.style.display = "none";
}
```

- 

This is only my last try, I have tried with add event listeners, with If and Boolean, but all i know is JS and no php.

Someone please shine some light on this because I know it is not that complicated but I cannot find any answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use options page generator (you can only take form bit and register option if already have option page registered for your plugin).
https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-option-page-generator/

Don't use onclick there to manipulate front end.
Find header_title in your .php template and wrap it in

```
$titleCheck = get_option( 'title_option_name' );  
if ($titleCheck) {
THIS IS WHERE YOU RENDER YOUR TITLE FIELD
}
```